# Convert an A4R (A4 lanscape) scanned jpeg, to A4R (A4 lanscape) pdf

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick

I have have scanned an A4R paper sheet to a 2048x1443 jpg file.

EDIT1 : It's already rotated to landscape (2048x1443).
END OF EDIT1

Now if I try convert it with this command :

```
$ convert -page A4R A4R_Scanned.jpg A4R_Scanned.pdf
$ echo $?
0
```

EDIT2 : There was no error message regarding the A4R argument.
END OF EDIT2

I get a blank US Letter, Portrait page :

```
$ identify A4R_Scanned.pdf
   **** Warning:  File has an empty MediaBox. Using the current page size instead.
                  Output may be incorrect.
   **** Warning:  File has an empty MediaBox. Using the current page size instead.
                  Output may be incorrect.
A4R_Scanned.pdf PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 63.2K
```

EDIT3 : I tried another solution :

```
$ convert -page A4 -rotate 90 A4R_Scanned.jpg A4R_Scanned2A4.pdf
```

This gives a satisfying A4 document with no visible quality loss but I need to rotate it back to have an A4R (landscape).

When I do that, more quality is lost and that's visible :

```
$ convert -rotate -90 A4R_Scanned2A4.pdf A4R_Scanned2A4R.pdf
```

Now, my question is : How do I rotate the document back without loosing too much quality ?

END OF EDIT3

EDIT4 : Thanks to dirkt, the conversion can be done in one step and the quality is good :-) :

```
$ convert -page 842x595 A4R_Scanned.jpg A4R_Scanned2A4R.pdf
```

END OF EDIT4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple look at the [documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page) of the `-page` command line options shows that `A4R` doesn't exist (and I've never heard of a format with this name). If you mean A4, use `-page A4` instead. If you mean something like "A4 with an extra feature that's called R", you possibly have to do some extra things for "R", whatever that is.

**Edit**: If "R" means "rotated", have a look at the `-rotate` option.

I wouldn't be surprised if you also got an error message while calling `convert` which complained about this.

**Edit**

If I understand the edit's correctly, the problem is that you want landscape without rotating. The problem here is that the PDF format has various ways to flag "landscape": You can either have actual landscape (bounding box width greater than height), or you can store a portrait image and add a `\Rotation` entry. (Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050743/how-to-find-whether-pdf-has-landscape-orientation-or-portrait)). And what various tools do in this respect is always a bit hit or miss.

One of the simplest things you can try is to use `-page 842x595` (A4 is just a shorthand for `595x842`) and see what happens.

Anything else will probably require to take a closer look at what happens by inspecting the PDFs that are generated by your imagemagick/graphicsmagick `convert` and you current version.

Comment: A4R sounds to me like a shorthand some multifunction copier/printers might use for "A4 rotated", or in other words, A4 paper in landscape orientation.

Comment: @dirkt Hi, please see my EDITs.